# How to encode characters with UTF-8 for all pages on the server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts

In my controller files i keep having to include the following line of code so that foreign charcters appearing properly. is there a better way? how can I make text encode to utf-8 automatically unless I specify otherwise?

```
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

I have tried adding these lines in my server.xml but it didn't make a difference.

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoder="UTF-8"
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3" URIEncoder="UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a filter to your web.xml that converts everything to UTF-8. I use Spring alot which provides a filter to do this:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The filter doesn't do really more than you do here, except that you won't have to include it in your controller. Struts will probably also provide a filter like this, else it is pretty easy to write yourself.